# Django INNER JOIN by field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Say I have a model that is

```
class Bottles(models.Model)
    BottleCode = models.IntegerField()

class Labels(models.Model)
    LabelCode = models.IntegerField()
```

How do I get a queryset of Bottles where the BottleCode and LabelCode are equal? (i.e. Bottles and Labels with no common Code are excluded)

Comment: Be careful, your question is a clear symptom that your model is poorly designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved via [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra):

```
Bottles.objects.extra(where=["Bottles.BottleCode in (select Labels.LabelCode from Labels)"])
```

You may also need to add an app name prefix to the table names, e.g. `app_bottles` instead of `bottles`.

Though @danihp has a point here, if you would often encounter queries like these, when you are trying to relate unrelated models - you should probably think about changing your model design.